# Is there a Hamiltonian path though a Menger sponge of level-n?

Tags: fractals, hamiltonian-path

This is a thought that I was having while building a model of a level 4 Menger sponge in minecraft.

Imagine a Menger sponge to be built of cubic voxels the same size as the smallest void. You can build a graph of this where each node is a voxel and there is an arc between them if that voxel is adjacent.

If you take this adjacency graph is there a hamiltonian path with in it?

For the level 1 case by simple inspection I've worked out no such path exists but I am unsure when we move to higher levels.

Comment: The corner  voxel/node has degree 3, and its three neighbours are all of degree 2. It is easy to show that the Hamiltonian path will have to start/end at one of those degree 2 nodes. Unfortunately there are 8 such corners and a path has only two start/end nodes.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: That comment is an answer!  Could you turn it into one, or if not, do you mind if I (or anyone else who gets to it sooner) does so?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Go right ahead if you want.